# python: print using carriage return and comma not working

Tags: python, newline, carriage-return

I need to print over one line in a loop (Python 3.x). Looking around on SO already, I put this line in my code:

```
print('{0} imported\r'.format(tot),)
```

However, it still prints multiple lines when looped through. I have also tried

```
sys.stdout.write('{0} imported\r'.format(tot))
```

but this doesn't print **anything** to the console...

Anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write()` works for me .. you have `import sys`. Are you trying to overlay the output on the same line?

Comment: If you are trying to get the same effect as `print text,` from python 2.x, you need to use the `end` argument, as in `print(text, end='')`.  The comma at the end of the function arguments has no effect.

Comment: Not sure about "from 2.x".  The line `print(text, end='')` gives me a syntax error at the `=`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the first case, some systems will treat `\r` as a newline. In the second case, you didn't `flush` the line. Try this:

```
sys.stdout.write('{0} imported\r'.format(tot))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Flushing the line isn't necessary on all systems either, as Levon reminds me -- but it's generally a good idea when using `\r` this way.

Comment: @kevlar1818 As I mentioned in the comment, that worked for me (even w/o flushing the output buffer) ... odd

Comment: The `sys.stdout.flush()` was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

If you want to overwrite your last line you need to add \r (character return) and end="" so that you do not go to the next line.

```
values = range(0, 100)
for i in values:
    print ("\rComplete: ", i, "%", end="")
print ("\rComplete: 100%")
```

Answer (score 15):

I prefer to use the solution of Jan but in this way:

```
values = range(0, 101)
for i in values:
  print ("Complete: ", i, "%", end="\r")
print ()
```