# Python requests.text adding empty lines

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use GET through requests to get current code for a project of mine hosted on Github to have an auto update system of some sort, but whenever I GET the latest latest code (raw github file) it adds blank lines in between lines of code, for example:

```
def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name =='nt' else 'clear')
clear()
```

becomes

```
def clear():

    os.system('cls' if os.name =='nt' else 'clear')

clear()
```

It is adding unnecessary lines in between everything when their is none in the code. My code is:

```
import requests, time

ask = input('Would you like to update to the latest version of Switchence? ') # Switchence is the name of my app
if ask == 'y' or ask == 'yes':
    print('Ok, updating...')
    try:
        onlineVersion = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aethese/Switchence/main/main.py')
        if onlineVersion.status_code != 200:
            print(f'[ERROR] status code is not 200, it is {onlineVersion.status_code} so the program will not update')
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            onlineVersion = onlineVersion.text
            with open('autoupdate.py', 'w') as file: # autoupdate.py is my test file
                file.write(onlineVersion)
            print('Successfully updated to latest version! Rerun the program to use the newest version!')
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Couldn\'t get latest latest update | {error}')
        time.sleep(5)
elif ask == 'n' or ask == 'no':
    print('Ok, you will not update to the latest version')
    time.sleep(5)
else:
    print('The only acceptable answers are Yes or No')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Can someone help me or explain to me why my code won't work? I am running latest pip version of requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow opening the file in binary mode seems to fix the issue:

```
onlineVersion = onlineVersion.content
with open('autoupdate.py', 'wb') as file: # autoupdate.py is my test file
    file.write(onlineVersion)
```

This has probably something to do with [Python inserts both a carriage return and a line feed after variable, instead of just line feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121179/python-inserts-both-a-carriage-return-and-a-line-feed-after-variable-instead-of)

Comment: Thanks! That did solve my problem, I did not consider opening it in binary mode would fix my issue, thanks a ton!