# Python raising exception where message has carriage return \r control character

Tags: python, exception, repr, control-characters

I am performing serial communications with an electronic device, and the end of a response message is dictated by a carriage return (`\r`).  If the response is garbled, I raise a custom exception.  I would like my exception message to show the raw response, which may include a carriage return.

I noticed that carriage returns sort of messes up printing/representation of Python's exceptions.

Is there any way to have Python's exceptions use something like `repr`?

---

**Potential Workaround**

I could make a custom exception class and override some behavior to replace `\r` with `"CR"`, but I am unsure if there is a simpler way.

I am also unsure which dunder methods to use, nor where to find which dunder methods to use.

---

**What I Am Seeing**

Input:

```py
class SerError(Exception):
    """Serial communications error."""


some_msg = f"some_serial\rmessage."
print(f"some_msg = {some_msg}.\nrepr(some_msg) = {repr(some_msg)}.")
raise SerError(some_msg)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
message..SerError: some_serial
```

You can see Python is interpreting the control character `\r` by resetting the cursor to the beginning of the line, where it prints the remainder of the message.

I do not like this behavior, as it overwrites my exception message, as opposed to printing the original message.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018188/python-print-using-carriage-return-and-comma-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining a custom exception, you can override the `__str__()` method to have it return the `repr` that you want:

```py
class SerError(Exception):
    """Serial communications error."""
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.args[0])
```

The `self.args[0]` selects only the first element of the tuple, otherwise it would return the `repr` of a tuple with one or more arguments.

Comment: Thank you @Craig!  I used `repr(self.args[0])[1:-1]` to also remove the quotes from `repr`